# Solution of a specific matrix equation with unknown inside trace. Is it correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, trace

Please analyze whether the following solution is correct.

We have the matrix differential equation about **Q**:

$$ \operatorname{tr} \left( \left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)^{-1}d\textbf{Q} \right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{\textbf{H}^T\textbf{H}d\textbf{Q}}{\left( r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P} \right)\textbf{H}^T \right)^2} \right) $$

where **Q** and **P** are symmetric positive definite matrices, **P** is independent of **Q**, *r* is a scalar constant, and **H** is a row matrix

$
\textbf{H}=\left[ 0, 0, ... 0, 1 \right]
$.

$
tr\left[ \left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)^{-1}d\textbf{Q} \right]=tr\left[ \frac{\textbf{H}d\textbf{Q}\textbf{H}^T}{\left[ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P} \right)\textbf{H}^T \right]^2} \right]
$;

$
tr\left[ \left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)^{-1}d\textbf{Q} \right]=\frac{\textbf{H}d\textbf{Q}\textbf{H}^T}{n\left[ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P} \right)\textbf{H}^T \right]^2} tr\left( \textbf{I} \right)
$,

where **I** is the identity matrix and *n* is its rank.

We integrate both sides of the equation under the trace sign:

$
tr\left[\int_{}^{} \left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)^{-1}d\textbf{Q} \right]=tr\left[ \frac{\textbf{I}}{n} \right]\int_{}^{}\frac{\textbf{H}d\textbf{Q}\textbf{H}^T}{\left[ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P} \right)\textbf{H}^T \right]^2}
$.

We add the constants under the sign of the differential:

$
tr\left[\int_{}^{} \left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)^{-1}d\left( \textbf{Q+P} \right) \right]=tr\left( \frac{\textbf{I}}{n} \right)\int_{}^{}\frac{d\left(r+ \textbf{HQ}\textbf{H}^T +\textbf{HP}\textbf{H}^T\right)}{\left( r+\textbf{HQ}\textbf{H}^T+\textbf{H}\textbf{P}\textbf{H}^T  \right)^2}
$.

We integrate:

$
tr\left[ \ln\left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)+\textbf{C} \right]=-tr\left[ \frac{\textbf{I}}{n} \right]\left( \frac{1}{ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P} \right)\textbf{H}^T}+c \right)
$,

where **C** is a constant matrix, *c* is scalar constant .
The above equation has an infinite number of solutions, but we can get one of all by getting rid of the matrix trace:

$
\ln\left( \textbf{Q+P} \right)=- \frac{1}{n\left[ r+\textbf{HQ}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P}\right)\textbf{H}^T \right]}\textbf{I}-\frac{c\textbf{I}}{n}-\textbf{C}
$.

We get rid of the logarithm:

$
\textbf{Q+P} =\exp\left[ - \frac{1}{ n\left[ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P}\right)\textbf{H}^T\right]} \right]\exp\left( -\frac{c\textbf{I}}{n}-\textbf{C} \right)
$.

We obtain an implicit solution of the equation up to the constant matrix **B**:

$
\textbf{Q} =\textbf{B}\exp\left[ - \frac{1}{ n\left[ r+\textbf{H}\left( \textbf{Q}+\textbf{P}\right)\textbf{H}^T\right]} \right]-\textbf{P}
$,

where

$
\textbf{B}=\exp\left( -\frac{c\textbf{I}}{n}-\textbf{C} \right)
$.

Comment: What is the motivation?  Where does this come from?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo This is part of a numerical optimization problem with the determinant in the objective function. I am trying to reduce the number of independent parameters.

Comment: And why does this optimization problem need to be solved?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The optimization problem is engineering, not mathematical, and has no place in this community. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I disagree.  I would append a section pertaining to the motivation so that other people trying to solve the same engineering problem can find this question.  Attempting to hide the motivation does not give you anything valuable, and merely turns people off